# Is domain controller necessary for BizTalk server 2010 in order to run BizTalk WCF published services?

Tags: iis-7, windows-server-2008, biztalk, esb, biztalk-2010

I have a BizTalk Server 2010 installed in windows server 2008 R2. When i publish wcf service through wizard and try to run the service on browser, it returns an error :

> The Messaging Engine failed to register the adapter for
>   "WCF-BasicHttp" for the receive location
>   "/OrderProcessingDescription/OrderProcessService.svc". Please verify
>   that the receive location exists, and that the isolated adapter runs
>   under an account that has access to the BizTalk databases.

Also account used in the application pool is a member of the BizTalk Isolated Host Users group.

One thing which is not installed in Windows Server 2010 is Domain Controller. Please let me know if I need to install it .

Answer (score 2):

please see the following thread to check the actual error:
[Link to thread](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36397/BizTalk-Error-Please-verify-that-the-receive-locat)

Answer from thread:

> To solve this issue check the application pool security user account
>   in the IIS. Add that user account into the BizTalk Isolated Host Users
>   group. Or change the application pool to the pool which user is
>   already a member of the BizTalk Isolated Host Users Group.

The domain controller feature actually has very little to do with this and the feature is likely not to be installed on your BizTalk server.

Comment: I already have all these settings configured. But it still giving this error. @PieterVandenheede

Comment: Is your receive location working and point to the exact same Virtual Directory as set in IIS?

Comment: Yes, recieve location is enabled and running. and also pointing to correct virtual directory. @PieterVandenheede

Comment: @MukeshSakre Can you also check if Anonymous authentication is enabled for the web service in IIS and if so, is it set to use IUSR or the app pool account?

Comment: Anonymous authentication is enabled for the web service and it is using app pool account. @Rajesh Ramamirtham

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the publishing wizard:

- Ensure that there is an app pool available which is linked to a BTS Isolated host account (you seem to have done this).
- Ensure that the app/virtual directory created by the wizard in IIS for the basicHttp endpoint is configured to use this app pool.
- Ensure that the corresponding receive port is created, and enabled (look in the BizTalk admin console).
- Also ensure that the BTS host process for the receive port is running.