# Does BizTalk Server 2010 works with SQL express 2008 R2?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, iis-7.5, biztalk, esb, biztalk-2010

Pl let me know that does BizTalk Server 2010 works with SQL express 2008 R2?

Also the below error is coming When i publish wcf service through wizard and try to run the service on browser :-

The Messaging Engine failed to register the adapter for "WCF-BasicHttp" for the receive location "/OrderProcessingDescription/OrderProcessService.svc". Please verify that the receive location exists, and that the isolated adapter runs under an account that has access to the BizTalk databases

see ref : [Is domain controller necessary for BizTalk server 2010 in order to run BizTalk WCF published services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17315562/is-domain-controller-necessary-for-biztalk-server-2010-in-order-to-run-biztalk-w)

Is this error coming might be because of SQL express 2008 R2.

Answer (score 2):

Saravana Kumar has [a post](http://blogs.biztalk360.com/biztalk-server-with-sqlexpress/) on how SQL Express and BizTalk work together (or rather how they don't ;)).

Is the service (the IIS application pool) actually running in a user context with access to BizTalk databases? For example the [BizTalk Isolated Host Users](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa577661.aspx) group?